# Google Places Autocomplete on dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, dynamic, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

Good day.

I'm trying to add Google Places Autocomplete on dynamically created inputs using code below:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var _autoComplCounter = 0;

function assignAutoCompl(_id)
{
    var _autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(_id));
    _autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
    google.maps.event.addListener(_autocomplete, 'place_changed', function()
    {
        //processing code
    });
}

function CreateElem()
{
    var _id = "AutoCompl" + _autoComplCounter;
    _autoComplCounter++;

    var container = document.getElementById('AutoComplInputs');
    container.innerHTML += "<br>" + _id;

    var _elem_for_upd = document.createElement("input");
    _elem_for_upd.type = "text";
    _elem_for_upd.id = _id;
    container.appendChild(_elem_for_upd);

    assignAutoCompl(_id);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="AutoComplInputs"></div>
    <input type='button' value='Add' onclick='CreateElem();'>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I press on button, autocomplete works only on last input, and all prevoius become broken. I think that it can be connected to dynamic creation of inputs, as the code below works fine:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var _autoComplCounter = 0;

function assignAutoCompl(_id)
{
    document.getElementById(_id).hidden = false;
    var _autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(_id));
    _autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
    google.maps.event.addListener(_autocomplete, 'place_changed', function()
    {
        //processing code
    });
}

function CreateElem()
{
    assignAutoCompl("AutoCompl0");
    assignAutoCompl("AutoCompl1");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="AutoComplInputs">
        <input id="AutoCompl0" type="text" hidden>
        <input id="AutoCompl1" type="text" hidden>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Add' onclick='CreateElem();'>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `innerHTML` to add content to `container`, you will lose all handlers bound to existing elements.

Use appendChild instead:

```
container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(_id));
```